# Customize Google Map current Blue icon and Blue icon Pointer

Tags: android, google-maps

I am almost finished my app. But the one thing what i want to change in Google Map is my Current location Blue icon and Blue icon pointer when navigate to another location(means update location).

What I need to display in my Google Map in my app is[image]

And in my app what i have,

[image]

So please can anybody tell me how can we customize that current location Blue icon??

Help will be appreciated!!